# "Badly" versus "poorly"

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

I was saying to an American friend, "I pronounce still bad," which she said is a mistake, saying it should be *poorly*.

Well, I get that part, but when I asked if I can say *badly*, she said I shouldn't. I asked an Englishman and he said it's perfectly fine. So is it a difference between American English and British English, or am I just not getting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NOAD reports that the first meaning of *poorly* is "in a way or at a level that is considered inadequate," while the first meaning of *badly* is "in an unsatisfactory, inadequate, or unsuccessful way."

The NOAD has also a note about the usage of *bad*.

> Confusion in the use of *bad* versus *badly* usually has to do with verbs called copulas, such as *feel* or *seem*. Thus, standard usage calls for *I feel bad*, not *I feel badly*. As a precise speaker or writer would explain, *I feel badly* means "I do not have a good sense of touch."

There is a slight difference between *poorly*, and *badly*: *Poorly* should be used when something is considered inadequate, while *badly* should be used when something is inadequate.

> I work in a badly managed company.
>   He spelt a few poorly articulated words.

Comment: so I guess as I said it in a self-reflective manner based on my observation (I mean I know that I do not follow a standard pronunciation), I could say badly, right?

Comment: When referring to pronunciation, I would say _poorly_.

Comment: To me (UK) both "badly" and "poorly" are acceptable, but "badly" sounds a more harsh judgment, "poorly" a gentler one.

Answer (score 5):

In colloquial English English, as opposed to American English, "I feel poorly" means "I feel ill." It is connected exclusively to one's health. If, for example, it were used to express poor tactile sense it would have some qualifying word or phrase; eg. "I feel things very poorly with my fingers."

Some dialects might use "badly" in the same way, but generally this is used of emotions, as when one has hurt someone's feelings one might say, "I feel very badly about that.

"Badly" can be used in other ways, such as "The motor repairs were done very badly," (In an unsatisfactory manner.)

Answer (score 2):

My grandmother corrected me on saying badly I think because it implied doing wrong whereas poorly meant it was not up to par or sufficient.  As I think about it there are probably more adequate words like insuffciently that would be clearer in meaning.  Anyway whether right or wrong, I cringe when I hear someone say they are performing badly.  It hurts my ears.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'still' must be placed after "I" : I still pronounce...

However, it's much better to say: My pronunciation is still poor / bad.

Comment: well I'm aware that I should/could say it differently, I was more wondering about the difference between poor and bad in this context. Thanks for the "still" anyway, after asking this question I even more think that my English is awful.

Comment: Answer off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use "bad/badly" vs. "poor/poorly", I don't think there's much difference in this context. They both are grammatical and understandable here as "I still do not pronounce well".

There is a trend in American English to drop 'ly' so that something that acts like an adverb instead looks like an adjective. So

> I talk bad

is OK

This is similar to saying

> I don't talk too good

where 'well' the adverb is replaced by 'good' the adjective.

(which is classic 'ungrammatical' speech but is what people might say acceptably in a very colloquial/low register setting.)

One most likely would not use 'poor' in this context because it would really stand out as weird ('poor' in this meaning of 'not good' is not particularly common in American English).

"I pronounce poorly", "I pronounce badly", and "I pronounce bad" are all fine in AmE, the last one not so much only because "pronounce", as a more technical word, is of higher register than "bad" and so it sounds incongruous.

Comment: I have to admit that as a Brit, my immediate reaction to "I talk bad" is "Yes.  Yes, you do." :-)

Comment: @Rhodri: that's the annoying thing about grammar, there's a difference between what you should do and what you really do. "I talk bad" definitely sounds like fingernails across a blackboard to me, and I believe a teacher at school should take off points for using it, but it is a purely legal grammatical construct for some speakers/registers of AmE.

Comment: If you're not a native, I wouldn't advise going about dropping 'ly' at random from adverbs in American English. There are a lot of rules about when you can and can't do it that I think I intuitively know but I certainly don't understand. You'll end up sounding bad.

Comment: @PeterShor: do you have some examples? I don't doubt them, it's just that talking and listening lately, I feel like in informal talk, nothing has '-ly' anymore. Maybe with technical words? But then you're almost by default not talking informally.

Comment: Yes. You can certainly say "He drives slow". But if you say "He slow drove down the street, looking for the correct house," it sounds absolutely terrible to my ear.

Comment: @PeterShor: oh OK. I totally agree there. How about right after the verb though?

Comment: "He drove slow down the street." sounds okay. But I don't think "He leafed slow through the book." sounds good at all. I'm trying to figure out whether "He drove slow down the street." and "He drove slowly down the street." mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @PeterShor: I think the problem with the 'leafed' sentence is not the grammar difficulty of 'slow' vs 'slowly' but that the registers are mixed. One would never ever ever use the formal vocabulary item 'leafed' in the same mindset as using the informal 'slow'. As to if the meanings of two sentences are the same, one with 'slow', one with 'slowly'...I can't tell.

Comment: I don't think it's the formality. "They fell in love" can certainly be in an informal register, but "They fell slow in love," sounds really bad to me (although it's fine with "slowly").

Answer (score -1):

Either "I feel poorly" or "I feel badly" would be a grammatically incorrect way to express anything other than a handicap. If you were trying to express that you felt ill, you'd do better to say, "I feel unwell." Or, if trying to express guilt or remorse, "I feel bad" would be correct.

Yes, I know the general rule is that adverbs describe verbs and adjectives describe nouns; however, in this case, the adjective "bad" isn't describing the verb "feel," but rather the subject pronoun "I." In other words, you're implying, "I feel [like a] bad [person]."

Although most of us would shy away from going so far as to say, "I feel evil," that would make much more sense than saying, "I feel evilly."